# How can I extract key word value from a string

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I am using this tool https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to test my grok parser. The origin string I have is something like:

```
2020-05-01 01:59:10 server1 17.5.36.8 POST /v1/user.aspx r=1000&11:59:11.219&Method=Start&Credentials=xxxxxx:++http://localhost/v1/user.aspx&Reque
```

I'd like to parse the data to:

```
{
Method: Start,
r: 1000
Credential: xxxxx
}
```

I am looking at the parser https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns but I can't find a good one to use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this using solely grok patterns. If you're also using Logstash, you can try the following solution:

The pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s%{GREEDYDATA:server}\s%{IP:ip}\s%{GREEDYDATA:request_type}\s%{PATH:path}\sr=%{NUMBER:r}&%{TIME:some_time}&Method=%{GREEDYDATA:method}&Credentials=%{GREEDYDATA:username}:%{GREEDYDATA:password}%{MY_URI:uri}
```

It works with the [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns):

```
MY_URI http://(?:%{USER}(?::[^@]*)?@)?(?:%{URIHOST})?(?:%{URIPATHPARAM})?
```

I used the custom pattern because the %{URIPROTO} from the original %{URI} pattern won't separate credentials from the uri properly. I assumed that credentials are given in the following format:

```
username:password
```

In case I'm wrong, please replace:

```
Credentials=%{GREEDYDATA:username}:%{GREEDYDATA:password}
```

with:

```
Credentials=%{GREEDYDATA:credentials}
```

If the `:++` string separates credentials from uri, you can use it to apply the %{URI} instead of %{MY_URI}.

The pattern works in the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). However the output is more readable in the [Grok Constructor Matcher](https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match).

Since you're only interested in some fields, use the [remove_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field) plugin. Use the [add_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) plugin to enclose the result in a new field.

Your `logstash.conf` file may look like this (if you place the file with the custom pattern in the `patterns` directory alongside the config file):

```
# logstash.conf
…
filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ["./patterns"]
        match => {
            "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s%{GREEDYDATA:server}\s%{IP:ip}\s%{GREEDYDATA:request_type}\s%{PATH:path}\sr=%{NUMBER:r}&%{TIME:some_time}&Method=%{GREEDYDATA:method}&Credentials=%{GREEDYDATA:username}:%{GREEDYDATA:password}%{MY_URI:uri}"
        }
    mutate {
            add_field => { "result" => "Method: %{method}, r: %{r} Credential: %{username}}
            remove_field => ["timestamp", "server", "ip", "request_type", "path", "some_time", "password", "uri", "method", "r", "username"]
        }
    }
…
```